# Reading gzipped payload of a rabbitmq message with pika

Tags: python-3.x, http, rabbitmq, gzip, pika

being desperate after two days of google.
I am consuming a message with pika coming from rabbitmq.
I know it is base64 and the content_encoding is gzip.
I got it working to encode the bytes body into utf-8.
Now I still need to decompress it somehow. Here is the code so far:

```py
    1 def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
    2    if properties.content_encoding == 'gzip':
    3    
    4        decoded_body  = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(body), 'utf-8'))
    5        #eliminating the leading 'b
    6        decoded_body = decoded_body.decode()
    7
    8        #this snippet is just copied from another solution
    9        buf = io.StringIO(decoded_body)
    10       f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
    11       decompressed_body = f.read()
    12       print(decompressed_body)
```

The following error message occurs at line 11.

```
 return self._buffer[read:] + \
 TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Obviously there is a "\" in the gzip file which I need to convert into b"\".
But I dont know how.
Am I on the right track at all or can it be solved easier?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is the payload of the message when opening it in rabbitmq:
AFN3oPUfiwgAAAAAAAQAhU89T8MwEP0ryGJrHJ3t2mo8AqqK+BhIqGC8JKc0UuKUxBmqqv+di4pYGFhOenfv495ZvNA0YUOv2JPw4n77ke4Ix1gSRpGIPY1T
OwS+qFQzLtqe8oj9kTcatJJgpDaFWnvrPOg0g40Ca1agPADz30P7NdPjA9OzUpFzTktnMyfXWNYSyVmZmUpXCg2ylhX5MI/V8srTcPgc5tCkGzAgTZrnMn+W
AFYttALHhqLwYe66RLwRp0xxybkuflrdDfVJ+LO4jafjn3rJDUO24rnDUHf/h/5Kt+MSGCo2FwD+2vZy+QYahuynTgEAAA==

This is what I am getting when printing the body without any encoding:
b"\x00Sw\xa0\xf5\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x85O=O\xc30\x10\xfd+\xc8bk\x1c\x9d\xed\xdaj<\x02\xaa\x8a\xf8\x18H\xa8`\xbc$\xa74R\xe2\x94\xc4\x19\xaa\xaa\xff\x9d\x8b\x8aX\x18XNzw\xef\xe3\xdeY\xbc\xd04aC\xaf\xd8\x93\xf0\xe2~\xfb\x91\xee\x08\xc7X\x12F\x91\x88=\x8dS;\x04\xbe\xa8T3.\xda\x9e\xf2\x88\xfd\x917\x1a\xb4\x92`\xa46\x85Z{\xeb<\xe84\x83\x8d\x02kV\xa0<\x00\xf3\xdfC\xfb5\xd3\xe3\x03\xd3\xb3R\x91sNKg3'\xd7X\xd6\x12\xc9Y\x99\x99JW\n\r\xb2\x96\x15\xf90\x8f\xd5\xf2\xca\xd3p\xf8\x1c\xe6\xd0\xa4\x1b0 M\x9a\xe72\x7f\x96\x00V-\xb4\x02\xc7\x86\xa2\xf0a\xee\xbaD\xbc\x11\xa7Lq\xc9\xb9.~Z\xdd\r\xf5I\xf8\xb3\xb8\x8d\xa7\xe3\x9fz\xc9\rC\xb6\xe2\xb9\xc3Pw\xff\x87\xfeJ\xb7\xe3\x12\x18*6\x17\x00\xfe\xda\xf6r\xf9\x06\x1a\x86\xec\xa7N\x01\x00\x00"

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you unzip the data.

Comment: in the callback function I skipped the unnecessary bytes

`def callback(channel, method, properties, body): 
if properties.content_encoding == 'gzip':
for count, bite in enumerate(body):
            if body[count] == 31 and body[count + 1] == 139:
                break
    try:
        decompressed_body = gzip.decompress(body[count:])
        print("gzipped: {} \n".format(decompressed_body.decode()))
    except:
            print("unzipped: {} \n".format(body))`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

There are five bytes in your message in front of the gzip stream. You need to start gzip decoding at the `1f 8b`.

Comment: hello Mark, thanks for your recommendation. I will try that and come back to you. How do you know where the gzip stream starts?

Comment: gzip streams always start with `1f 8b`.

Comment: dear Mark, now I was able to start decompressing but it lead me to EOF error:
raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "

The code was:
gzip.decompress(body[5:-1])

Is it because I cut the bytes in the beginning?

Comment: No. The `-1` is dropping the last byte. You want `body[5:]`.

Comment: dear Mark, thank you so much. Now it works. After unzipping the message I am also able to read the payload in plaintext without decoding base64 either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of unnecessary encoding and decoding going on here.

Does this work?

```
buf = io.BytesIO(body)
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
decompressed_body = f.read()
print(decompressed_body)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.
when reading f.read() it is saying:

gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\x00S')

Comment: @m1ch4 Post the message as text in your question (not as an image).

Comment: @m1ch4 I suspect the message to be corrupt. If you write the binary to a file, it is still not a gzipped file. But I might be overlooking something in all these encodings.

Comment: I cant read any of the gzipped messages stored on rabbitmq. I dont expect all to be corrupted. At least I dont hope so :) 
Maybe there is another way of getting a plaintext body without doing all these encodings which I dont know.